# Wordpress custom authentication page

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm building site based on wordpress for my client that requires album/gallery authentication.
I've made custom plugin that stores galleries and images in custom tables in the database.
Now i want to create a simple page for clients so they can sign in with gallery name and 
password to it and browse their galleries.
I was thinking about making a page in wp admin and custom template for it and then handle authentication in there.

How would you do such authentication?

Comment: Why you don't try with a wp plugin that block just some content? And permit authentication.

Comment: Voting to close as *too broad*, there are too many possible answers (see [help/on-topic]) and they would be *too long*, basically a full blown plugin. Roadmap: 1) Use WP native user's system. 2) Find a plugin to handle users and privileges (there are few great and good) or code your own rules. 3) Create the interface (via theme template in the frontend or plugin page in the backend).

Comment: one way can be to put your login code in shortcode via http://wordpress.org/plugins/shortcode-exec-php/ and create a gallery login page by creating a "new page" in wp-admin having login page design along with shortcode to handle login.

Comment: I can't use native user system because it requires email for users. Each gallery have own login/password. 

Neo: I was thinking of something similiar and i think i'm gonna go that way.

Answer (score 0):

The basic approach is:

1. register a function with the admin_menu event
2. add your pages and sub-pages
3. verify permissions

Read [roles and capabilities](https://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities) in the Codex for details.

```
add_action('admin_menu', 'pluginprefix_admin_menu'); // 1

function pluginprefix_admin_menu() {
    //2
    $plugurl = plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ );
    /*
    add_menu_page( $page_title, $menu_title, $capability, $menu_slug,
                     $function, $icon_url, $position );

    add_submenu_page( $parent_slug, $page_title, $menu_title, $capability,
                        $menu_slug, $function );

    for example: */

    add_menu_page( 'Statistikk', 'Statistikk', 'edit_plugins',
                   'pluginprefix_main', 'pluginprefix_page_main',
                   "$plugurl/img/stats-menu.png", 25);

    add_submenu_page( 'pluginprefix_main', 'Statistikk - Instillinger',
                      'Instillinger', 'edit_plugins', 'pluginprefix_fields',
                      'pluginprefix_page_fields' );

function pluginprefix_page_main() {
    // 3
    if ( !current_user_can( 'manage_options' ) )  {
    wp_die( __( 'You do not have sufficient permissions to access this page.' ));
    }
    include( MY_TEMPLATES . 'settings_page.tpl.php' );

}
```

## . . .

I see. In that case;

1. create a form with login / password fields, and post it to ["wp-ajax"](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_ajax_%28action%29).
2. on the other end, compare the login and password with the stored and [salted hashes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salting_%28cryptography%29).
3. and finally set a [session variable](http://devondev.com/2012/02/03/using-the-php-session-in-wordpress/) indicating that the user can browse a certain album.

Comment: Well it's for admin side. I'm meant front end. 
Let me make it more clear. It's custom plugin, galleries have own table in the database and each gallery have own login and password. On the frontend client just type login and password to the gallery to be able to browse it : )